# JSOUP - parse a website and find information from it

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I played a little with JSOUP, but I can't get the information I want with it from a website and I need some help.
For example I have this [website](http://www.allmusic.com/), and I would like to extract some info like this :

```
-ROCK
--ACID ROCK
--PSYCHEDELIC ROCK
--BLUES ROCK
-----Aerosmith
----------One Way Street
-----AC/DC
----------Ain't No Fun (Waiting Round to Be a Millionaire)
```

With other words ... I want a list with genres containing lists with artist containing lists with songs ...

```
-Genre1
--Artist1
---Song1
---Song2
---Song3
--Artist2
---Song1
-Genre2
...
```

This is what i have so far (sorry for the messy code):

```
    package parser;
    import java.io.File; 
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


    public class HTMLParser {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

             String HTMLSTring = "<!DOCTYPE html>" 
                                + "<html>" 
                                + "<head>" 
                                + "<title>Music</title>" 
                                + "</head>" 
                                + "<body>" 
                                + "<table><tr><td><h1>Artists</h1></tr>" 
                                + "</table>" 
                                + "</body>" 
                                + "</html>";

             Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring); 

             String genre = "genres";
             String artist = "artist";
             String album = "album";
             String song = "song";

             //Document htmlFile = null;
             //Element div = html.body().getElementsByAttributeValueMatching(genre, null); 
            // String div = html.body().getElementsByAttributeValueMatching(genre, null).text(); 
             //String cssClass = div.className();


             List genreList = new ArrayList();

             String title = html.title(); 
             String h1 = html.body().getElementsByTag("h1").text();
             String h2 = html.body().getElementsByClass(genre).text();
             String gen = html.body().getAllElements().text();

             Document doc;

             try {

                 doc = Jsoup.connect("http://allmusic.com/").get();

                 title = doc.title(); 
                 h1 = doc.text();
                 h2 = doc.text();

                 } catch (IOException e) 
                 { 
                     e.printStackTrace(); 
                 } 

             System.out.println("Title : " + title);
             //System.out.println("h1 : "+ h1);
             //System.out.println("h2 : "+ h2);
             System.out.println("gen : all elements : " + gen);

        }

    }
```

And this is my output:

```
Title : AllMusic | Record Reviews, Streaming Songs, Genres & Bands
gen : all elements : Artists Artists Artists Artists Artists Artists
```

I haven't got so far ...
I don't know how to extract the information ... (e.g. type of genres, artists names ...)

Comment: Some projects out there already do this using JSoup. Take a look through their code to see how they did it: https://github.com/mozvip/dynamo/blob/master/dynamo-core/src/main/java/dynamo/backlog/tasks/music/LookupMusicArtistExecutor.java  and https://github.com/dimztimz/timska-rabota/tree/master/polzac-prototip/src/pesni